# Override archive with static page

Tags: wordpress, archive, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type created by a third party plugin say `portfolios`.

Instead of displaying an archive at http://www.example.com/portfolios I want to display a page where I'll insert a shortcode for a few customizations.

Is there a way to override default post_type archive page with a static page?

Answer (score 1):

In the archive page, lets say archive-portfolios.php, use `get_template_part` to include any other file you like instead of the default content. Or if you don't care for child theme override-compatibility, a straight up `include` will do.

You should also consider putting your customized content straight into the archive template.

Comment: the shortcode I mentioned is  from the same third party plugin. the plugin provides customizations only using shortcodes. so i just cant pull the content using `include`.